# How to send an email using JavaMail via Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail, sendmail, gmail-api

I am new in the APP Engine Google world but I have my project into there and to send emails I am using JavaMail API and it's working well, but I need to change the "From" field  to an non-existent account or different from my personal account (I am not sure if it's necessary register in APP Engine the account what I need to appear in the "From" field). The emails that I have sent use my account authenticated in the "From" field (which it is obvious, isn't it). So the question is if it is possible? I read many websites about this question also from this website but I still not working.
Google APP engine has Gmail API in the API manager, but I am no sure if it's the same as using JavaMail API.

Some of my code that sends emails but using the authentication from my account:

```
public void sendEmail(String[] recipients, String subject, String body, String username, String password) {

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //I tried disabling this but it not works
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //I tried with another port

//I tried without authentication from my account like this:
//Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null); 
//It not works
session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
     @Override
     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
     return new PasswordAuthentication(MailService.this.username, MailService.this.password);
    }
});

Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
// Here is the key, sending email not from authenticated account
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("whateveraccount@example.com", "whateveraccount.engine@example.com")); 
message.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse("whateveraccount@example.com",false));

//Sending to multiple recipients
Address[] to = new Address[recipients.length];
for (int i=0; i<recipients.length; i++) {
    to[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);
}

message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
message.setSubject(subject);

/**
 Multi part message email
 **/

Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

//body
MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlPart.setContent(body, "text/html");
multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

// adds attachments
String[] attachFiles = new String[2];
attachFiles[0] = "..path to send attachment..";
attachFiles[1] = "..path to send attachment..";

if(attachFiles != null && attachFiles.length > 0){
    for (String filePath : attachFiles) {
        MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        try {
            attachPart.attachFile(filePath);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
    }
}

message.setContent(multipart);
Transport.send(message);
}
```

Updated:
More specifically I need the configurations into Google App Engine.

Comment: Did you check the 'Who can send mail' link (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/#who_can_send_mail) from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a non-existent email address in the `setFrom()` call.

From [Sending Mail with the Mail API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api):

> 3. To set the message sender and recipient, use the InternetAddress class.
>
>    a. Identify the sender by calling the setFrom() method on the MimeMessage object. Optionally, you can provide a personal name as a
>      string in the second parameter. For more information on which email
>      addresses you can use as the sender address, see [Who can send
>      mail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/#who_can_send_mail).

And [Who can send mail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/#who_can_send_mail) spells out the restrictions for the sender email address:

> For security purposes, the sender address of a message must be one of
>   the following:
>
> - The Gmail or Google Apps Account of the user who is currently signed in
> - Any email address of the form anything@[APP_NAME].appspotmail.com or anything@[APP_ALIAS].appspotmail.com
> - Any email address listed in the Cloud Platform Console under [Email API Authorized Senders](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/appengine/settings)
>
> All email addresses on the [Email API Authorized Senders](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/appengine/settings) list need
>   to be valid Gmail or Google-hosted domain accounts. App Administrators
>   can add the following accounts to the list of Authorized Senders:
>
> - Their own email address
> - Any group for which they are an Owner or Manager
> - Applications hosted in a Google Apps domain: noreply@[DOMAIN].com, as long as noreply@[DOMAIN].com is a valid account (user or group).
>
> In addition, domain administrators of domains managed by Google Apps
>   can add any user in their domain to the list of authorized senders.

Comment: Yes I see. Do you know which part into App Engine configurations I can register that address or domain? And after that which methods need to be change? .for example: setFrom(new InternetAddress("anything@app_name.com");

Comment: The `Settings` -> `Application settings` part, which is where you land if you click on that "Email API Authorized Senders" link in the doc (https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/appengine/settings)

Answer (score 1):

By using Sendgrid you can send emails from other domains than the ones declared in the console.

You just have to do something like:

```
    SendGrid sendgrid = new SendGrid(Constants.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
    SendGrid.Email email = new SendGrid.Email();
    email.addTo("recipient@gmail.com");
    email.setFrom("whatever@whatever.com");
    email.setFromName("Whatever");
    email.setSubject(...);
    ....
```

The documentation is very good and it is straightforward to switch from AppEngine Mail API to Sendgrid

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/sendgrid